# Convert GIF to MP4 with ffmpeg with palette color

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Palettegen is ok:

```
ffmpeg()
.input('temp/' + input.hash)
.outputOptions(["-vf fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen"])
.output('temp/palette.png')
```

the conversion using the palette return a error:

Error: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_paletteuse_0

```
ffmpeg()
.input('color=' + input.bg)
.inputFormat('lavfi')
.input('temp/' + input.hash)
.inputFormat('gif')
.input('temp/palette.png')
.outputOptions('-lavfi paletteuse')
.complexFilter(["[0][1]scale2ref[bg][gif]", "[bg]setsar=1[bg]", "[bg][gif]overlay=shortest=1[o]", "[o]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"])
.outputOptions(['-pix_fmt yuv420p', '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov', '-movflags +faststart', '-crf 5'])
.toFormat('mp4')
.output('temp/final-' + input.hash)
```

ffmpeg final command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=ffffff -f gif -i temp/cf81f99083462f693406e8fd03ca7009 -i temp/palette.png -y -filter_complex [0][1]scale2ref[bg][gif];[bg]setsar=1[bg];[bg][gif]overlay=shortest=1[o];[o]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 -lavfi paletteuse -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -movflags +faststart -crf 5 -f mp4 temp/final-cf81f99083462f693406e8fd03ca7009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=ffffff -f gif -i temp/cf81f99083462f693406e8fd03ca7009 -i temp/palette.png -y -filter_complex [0][1]scale2ref[bg][gif];[bg]setsar=1[bg];[bg][gif]overlay=shortest=1,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[o];[o][2]paletteuse -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart -crf 5 -f mp4 temp/final-cf81f99083462f693406e8fd03ca7009`

However, note that a GIF is already palettized and a H264 stream does not need to be.